# rdlc background image doesn't fit page

Tags: c#, report, rdlc

I created a rdlc report and set background image to it but I can't find a way to make the image fit the page seize like A4 or something .. the image is large and resizing it didn't fix the issue

how to set the background to fit the report page

thanks in advance

Comment: anyone know the answer ?